# Compiling a driver for MIPS architecture on 4.4 kernel

Tags: c, linux-kernel, cross-compiling, device

I am compiling a driver for MIPS architecture on 4.4 kernel. It seems compiler is not including

```
/linux-4.4.34/include/linux/types.h
```

but instead it includes

```
/linux-4.4.34/include/uapi/linux/types.h
```

Because of this I see below error.I did not include the path `/linux-4.4.34/include/uapi` in driver makefile.Could someone explain how can driver include the path `/include/linux` and not `/include/uapi/linux` ?

```
./arch/mips/include/asm/mipsregs.h:871:33: error: unknown type name 'u16'
```

Comment: can you post what is at /arch/mips/include/asm/mipsregs.h:871:33

Comment: For include a header under `include/uapi`, one should use directive `#include <uapi/..>`. So it is impossible to confuse this file with non-uapi one. As for type `u16`, for *mips* its definition is accessible with follow headers chain: `include/linux/types.h` - > `include/uapi/linux/types.h` -> `arch/mips/include/asm/types.h` -> `include/asm-generic/int-ll64.h`. Not sure why given definition is not available in your case. Please, provide complete error message (with chain of files, where error has been arised).

Comment: **u16** type is never declared by Linux headers included by user space(uapi) and for user space use **__u16** is used instead.

Comment: @SumitGemini: **u16** type is declared in `include/asm-generic/int-ll64.h`, which is **not** an *uapi*-header, thus it isn't used by user space. *uapi*-variant of this header (`include/uapi/asm-generic/int-ll64.h`) doesn't contain definition of this type.

Comment: @Tsyvarev, their *Makefile* and command line to call compiler is probably wrong. They most likely are trying to compile it as a (user space) application. **u16** is internal type for Linux kernel. User space should use **__u16** instead.

Comment: @anbu, not enough context.

Comment: @Tsyvarev If I define 'unsigned short u16' in header file arch/mips/include/uapi/asm/types.h, definition is available to driver. So, arch/include/asm/types.h able to include arch/mips/include/uapi/asm/types.h but not include/asm-generic/int-ll64.h ?

Comment: anbu: I agree with @0andriy in that your *usage of headers* is *likely* **wrong**. Linux kernel is a complex thing, and it operates correctly only with proper usage. But information you provide is insufficient for give more detailed help. Please, [edit] your question and include information I have asked in the first comment.

Comment: @anbu, *asm-generic* folder **is not** for direct use! You have to run `make ARCH=mips ...` to do this properly.

Comment: @0andriy In mipsisa32-be-elf.inc file, given the path /kernel/include/uapi in -isystem. This helps to solve the above compilation issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In mipsisa32-be-elf.inc file, given the path /kernel/include/uapi in -isystem compilation flag. This helps to solve the above compilation issue.